# Improve SQL query execution time

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have a dataGridView that displays data from a table, after I export these data as a xml file, I add the unique field to another table so I can display only non-exported data.

How I display only data that are not yet exported :

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    SqlCommand queryLocal = new SqlCommand("SELECT *uniqueField* FROM myTable 
WHERE *uniqueField* = " + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString().Trim().Replace("'","''"), con);
    var reader = queryLocal.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
        i--;
    }
    reader.Close();
}
```

The problem is that it takes more than 20 seconds to filter less than 400 rows.
How could I improve the performance here ?

Comment: First, obligatory "Fix your SQL injection attack vulnerability" warning.  Second, have you looked at the execution plan?  Third, doing this in a loop could also be a problem (select n+1 problem).

Comment: Your data provider is sql server - is this hosted somewhere for you or hosted yourself? How many rows are in your `dataGridView1`, and why do you have to query separately for each row in it? (That's probably your biggest performance loss). Do you have an index on `*uniqueField*`?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not simply running your original query again with a modified `WHERE` clause?

Comment: @Neil I retrieve the data from our ERP (ODBC) and compare them to a table in my local database (SQL Server Express). Atm there are 349 orders in the table but only 4 are displayed because they have not been exported yet. `*uniqueField*` is a unique fabrication order number.

Comment: Regarding your latest edit - removing single quotes from the input isn't fixing your SQL injection vulnerability. Use a parameter instead of munging a SQL string together - it'll remove the vulnerability _and_ help your execution speed (because SQL Server can re-use the same plan)

Comment: @Bridge So I tried using a parameter following the example shown [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2981/using-parameters-for-sql-server-queries-and-stored-procedures/) under "Parameterizing in SQL from other languages" and set my parameter value in the loop. I still have to wait 20+ seconds to get the filtered results.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
SqlCommand queryLocal = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT *uniqueField* FROM myTable");
var reader = queryLocal.ExecuteReader();

List<string> uniqueFields = new List<string>();
while (reader.Read())
    uniqueFields.Add(reader[0]);
reader.Close();

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (uniqueFields.Contains(dataGridView1.Rows[i])
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
        i--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Still takes the same amount of time